# Need help to fix a certain bug in Rock Paper Scissors Command | Discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord.py

So I have made a Rock paper Scissors command and it works almost perfectly. However, there is a bug that I need to fix it so badly. But I couldn't get any help from anywhere, unfortunately. Here's how the code works.
When you type '>rps' it sends an embed and asks to react to any of the emoji (rock, paper, or scissor). The bot has already chosen its item (with the help of random module). When I react to any emoji(rock, paper, and scissor emoji)it shows that I won, lost, or tied the match. It's all fine till here. But when you react to the same message manually(with any of the 3 emojis), the message changes again to win, lose, or draw embed. I want this to stop happening after the member has finished one match. Here's my code.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkMIV.png)

Sorry for not providing raw code, because the code sample was kinda buggy. I really appreciate it if someone helps me out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the event `on_reaction_add`, instead use a [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for), here's an example.

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["put", "emojis", "here"]

try:
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await channel.send("Timed out!")
else:
    if str(reaction.emoji) == rock:
        ...
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == paper:
        ...
    else: # Scissors
        ...
```

I also highly suggest just having one embed and editing it to fit your needs, you can define embed as

```py
em = discord.Embed(description=f"The bot chose {x}")
# Later on in the code
if bot_won:
    em.title = "You lost!"
    em.color = ...
elif user_won:
    em.title = "You won!"
    em.color = ...
else: # Draw
    em.title = "Draw!"
    em.color = ...
```